# Expected spy navigate to have been called with: [ [ '/members' ] ] but it was never called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service with a method that performs a http delete. If the delete has been succesfull, then I redirect to other page. When I test this method, if the parameter id I pass to it is correct, I expect router.navigate to have been called. But for some reason this does not happen, so I get this report from Jasmine:

Jasmine spec failure test:

```
Service: MemberDelete > Testing deleteMember() succesfully
Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ '/members' ] ]
but it was never called.
```

This is my testing file member-delete.service.spec.ts:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { memberMockObject } from 'src/app/components/member/member.mocks';
import {createSpyFromClass, Spy} from 'jasmine-auto-spies';
import { MemberDeleteService } from './member-delete.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

describe('Service: MemberDelete', () => {
  let service: MemberDeleteService;
  let mockHttp: HttpClientTestingModule;
  let mockHttpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers:[
        { provider: MemberDeleteService, useValue: service },
        { provider: HttpClient, useValue: createSpyFromClass(HttpClient) }
      ]
    });

    mockHttp = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    mockHttpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(MemberDeleteService);  
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockHttpTestingController.verify(); //Verifies that no requests are outstanding.
  });

  it('should ...', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Testing deleteMember() succesfully', () => {
    spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    service.deleteMember(memberMockObject.fakeMember.id);
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/members']);
  });

});
```

This is my service method from member-delete.service.ts:

```
public deleteMember(memberId: number): void {
    this._http.delete(`${this._membersUrl}/${memberId}`).subscribe({
      complete: () => {
        this.router.navigate(
          [`/members`]
        );
      },
      error: (error) =>  {this.handleError(error);} 
    });
  }
```

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're not passing a response for the `delete` and it is never going inside of the `subscribe` block.

Follow the lines with !!:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { memberMockObject } from 'src/app/components/member/member.mocks';
import {createSpyFromClass, Spy} from 'jasmine-auto-spies';
import { MemberDeleteService } from './member-delete.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

describe('Service: MemberDelete', () => {
  let service: MemberDeleteService;
  let mockHttp: HttpClientTestingModule;
  let mockHttpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers:[
        // !! remove below line and provide actual service for testing
        // { provider: MemberDeleteService, useValue: service },
        MemberDeleteService,
        // !! remove below line - HttpClientTestingModule mocks the HttpClient for you
        // { provider: HttpClient, useValue: createSpyFromClass(HttpClient) }
      ]
    });

    mockHttp = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    mockHttpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(MemberDeleteService);  
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockHttpTestingController.verify(); //Verifies that no requests are outstanding.
  });

  it('should ...', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
  // !! fakeAsync so we have better control of the subscribe
  it('Testing deleteMember() succesfully', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    service.deleteMember(memberMockObject.fakeMember.id);
    
    // !! expect a http request (find the pending request)
    const req = mockhttpTestingController.expectOne(request => request.url.includes(memberMockObject.fakeMember.id));
    // !! expect a delete method
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('Delete)';
    // !! flush below response for the pending http call
    req.flush({});
    // !! wait for the subscribe to complete before assertion (tick does this)
    tick();
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/members']);
  }));

});
```